# I edit my npm init config and now I can't reset it to default

Tags: npm, terminal, config, zsh

I was trying to set a default name so I didn't have to type it everytime, but whatever I did ended up messing up the creation of my package.json file. Now, when I type 'npm init' in a new project, instead of asking the usual prompts and setting up the file, it only includes 'name' and 'version'. The console log is below:

```
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help init` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
About to write to /Users/chris/Documents/App Brewery/todo-v1/package.json:

{
  "name": "",
  "version": ""
}


Is this OK? (yes)
```

I tried to edit my config file, but when i do, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn subl
npm ERR! path subl
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent spawn subl ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chris/.npm/_logs/2020-06-29T21_18_00_116Z-debug.log
```

and the log file is:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.1.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'config',
1 verbose cli   'edit' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v10.1.0
4 verbose stack Error: spawn subl ENOENT
4 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:227:19)
4 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:404:16)
4 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
5 verbose cwd /Users/chris/Documents/App Brewery/todo-v1
6 verbose Darwin 19.5.0
7 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "config" "edit"
8 verbose node v10.1.0
9 verbose npm  v6.14.5
10 error code ENOENT
11 error syscall spawn subl
12 error path subl
13 error errno ENOENT
14 error enoent spawn subl ENOENT
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I don't know enough about terminal etc to understand the errors or how to fix them. Can anybody give me some advice? I'm using zsh if that helps...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm all ears if somebody has a better answer, or can clarify things.

I was able to get something working again by creating a file .npm-init.js and using module.exports to add all the defaults back. I'm not sure if this will work in the long run or is the proper way to do things, but at least I have a package.json file again?

```
var cwd = process.cwd(),
  name = cwd.split("/").pop();

module.exports = {
  name: name,
  description: "",
  version: "1.0.0",
  main: "app.js",
  scripts: {
    start: "node app.js",
    dev: "nodemon app.js"
  },
  keywords: [],
  author: "",
  license: ""
};
```